# Login administrator c# from local database bug

Tags: c#, xaml, events, authentication, click

I have a problem when I try to connect an admin to my c# application.

I have created a local database to stock the main informations such as UserName, Password...

When the user enter the login interface, he enter his user name and password, then click to login like this:

```
<TextBox Name="UserNameBox"></TextBox>
<PasswordBox Name="PasswordBox"></PasswordBox>
<Button Content="Connection" Click="ConnectionClick"></Button>
```

The event click role is to check if the admin can log in, or not:

```
private void  ConnectionClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var username = UserNameBox.Text;
    var password = PasswordBox.Password;

    Admin admin = new Admin();

    if((username == admin.UserName) && (password == admin.Password))
    {
        this.Close()
        MainPage retourpageprincipale = new MainPage();
        retourpageprincipale.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bad Username/Password combo!");
    }
}
```

I have created some fake users into my local database (Admin) and when I enter the correct login/password, I have the MessageBox. I always have the MessageBox.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you storing your passwords in the localdb in plaintext?

Comment: can you look through your Admin object to see that you're in fact getting populated data?

Comment: In the code shown you create a new `Admin` instance but you don't access your database so you cannot expect any other behavior than the Messagebox being shown.

Comment: I currently store my password in the localdb.
I'm pretty new, what do you mean with plaintext? Not encrypted?

Comment: @Filburt: When i try to debug step by step, i see admin.Password and admin.UserName are null. Thought instanciate the admin db was enough, what can i do to access my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give You an answer, but I will show you what should be done in such cases:

1. Try to debug - put break point in line `if((username == admin.UserName) && (password == admin.Password))` and using watch expression try to find out where is the problem
2. If step one is impossible - try to log everything to file, but remember after find a bug delete this logging because you will log admin password :)

Above steps should give you the answer

Comment: Done a few minutes before. I see admin.Username and admin.Password are Null values.

It seems it's because I instantiate the db but I don't access my Database.

Comment: Are you use any ORM mapper (like Entity Framework)? And are you familiar with `SqlConnection`?

Comment: You can look on full tutorial like this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/use-local-database-file-in-window-application-C-Sharp/

Comment: I'll read the tutorial and come back to you if I have found what I need, or not.
Greetings.

Comment: I have a complication, cannot use system.data.SqlServerCe

I'll dl SQL compact server and install the dll, hope It'll be easier after.

Comment: Just change the class to proper one which allows you to connect to localdb

Comment: I'm sorry but.. What do you mean by Proper one? Is that missing something into my class? It only has the event click. Thanks for your help, I'm not used to manipulate local database on c# X/

Comment: Namespace `SqlServerCe` is for SQL CE, for localdb just use classes from namespace `SqlServer`

Comment: Okay, after some tries, i have this:

    public Page1()
        string queryString;
        string connectionString;
        private void ConnectionClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var username = UserNameBox.Text;
            var password = PasswordBox.Password;

            Admin admin = new Admin();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

Comment: if((username == admin.UserName) && (password == admin.Password))
            {
                this.Close();
                MainPage retourpageprincipale = new MainPage();
                retourpageprincipale.Show();
            }
And i have the error "The property ConnectionString has not been set". Moreover, when i mouseOver ConnectionString, visual studio tells me "connectionString is never assigned to, and will and will always have it's default value to NULL.

Comment: Did you declare `connectionString` to anything?

Comment: Oh... I missed declaring'em. I haven't declared queryString and neither declared connectionString. I suppose I have to assign connectionString the path for my local database. Have I to declare queryString too? And if yes, with what?
Thank you to continue to help me.

Comment: @Kraenys SO is not for question like this. Try to do simple tutorial on like this: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet for simple SQL or like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/jj193542.aspx for EntityFramework